# How many NOD like receptors in Human?

Tags: cell-biology, receptor, inflammation

This is pretty specific question maybe. Anybody have an estimate? For Toll Like Receptors there are something like 10...

http://www.jbc.org/content/276/4/2551.long

I'm only finding NOD1 and NOD2 => only 2?

Comment: The [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOD-like_receptor) wikipedia article has an aggregation of some of the different members of the NOD-like receptor family, and the [following](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2630772/) journal article goes over the nomenclature for the NLR family, and I believe will assist you.

Answer (score 1):

This [review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3797414/) 22 proteins in the NOD like human repetoire. It was published in 2013...

The families are broken down into 9 general groups according to their domain composition in Figure 1 from that review.  Most of them are not named "NOD".

[image]